# Bundle Install very beginner problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, bundler

Okay I'm basically day 1 at programming trying to follow Ruby On Rails 3 by Hartl... its not going well and I seem to be getting stuck every step of the way.

Right now I'm on page 19 & 20, not sure if I did it correct since it didn't really explain to well what it means but I get an error message. I did look thought other questions on here and didn't find any that were as beginner as mine that I might even understand.

For those without Hartl's book I found this page has it all: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:the_first_application

So where it says to update the **Gemfile** I amended the document in TextMate to read *gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'*. The book then says:

> Once you've assembled the proper **Gemfile**, install the gems using **bundle install:**
>
> $ bundle install
>
> Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/

What I did was amend the file and just hit save, I'm not sure if that's what it means by assembling it or if there is something more I need to press. Looking through the menus in Textmate, nothing jumped out at me. When I then typed in *bundle install* I get the message *unknown command bundle*

Any advice in basic terms would be very helpful as I'm obviously a complete beginner at this. Thanks!

Ryan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to use the bundler gem, you'll need to first install it.

```
gem install bundler
```

Then you can use:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: This is what frustrates me, the book cost me about $60... would it have been so terrible to include that especially when the intro says the book can be used by people with no programming experience.

Thankyou Simon that did the trick!

Comment: Fantastic, yeah I had the same problems when I started using ruby a long time ago, it's the small assumptions that authors leave out that really stump you.